# Kitkat ART (Android Runtime) optimization?

Tags: java, android, performance

I have heard, rightly or wrongly, that apps have to be written specifically with Android Runtime in mind in order for the bytecode to be changed into native machine code on a given device. Is this true? If so, how can I do that?

I know *similar* questions have been asked, but all the questions I have found were NDK related and this is not.

Comment: This is a different question because I am asking about app architecture and design and not changes in compiling.

Comment: There is nothing in your question about "app architecture and design".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be no need to write apps with this thing in mind, given the fact that the most important thing that changes is the way the apps are compiled.

On Android versions prior to KitKat, apps run with the "classical" *Just-in-Time* compiling scheme, that is, the code gets compiled *as it runs* (in simple terms). The difference with ART is that ART uses the so-called *Ahead-of-Time* compilation. This means that your same code gets pre-compiled *before* it actually runs on the device.

A very simple, but more technical, comparison can be found [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/realtime/v1r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rt.doc.10/realtime/aot.html).

I wouldn't worry much about it if I were you, because, except for those willing to dive into native code, most programmers write their code **on top** of all the layers of the classical app architecture; even *should* the runtime/compilation/etc change, that should not affect the way top-level code is written. And those willing to dive into native code will be able to do that in post-KitKat age as well.